# Jquery/Javascript issue on checkbox checked add row from one table to another with input box manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table on the say on the left side and it has four columns. I have another table on the right and I want two columns from the first column to be displayed on the right column.
All I am able to achieve is adding whole new row, where as I want columns formatted in row. I know I have to append html using jquery but can't find a way.

html code below for left table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="tbl1">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Items</th>
                      <th>Quantity/Calories</th>
                      <th>Portion</th>
                      <th>Approx. Callories</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr data-index="1">
                      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass"><span> Apple</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/65cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text" ng-model="qty"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-index="1">
                     <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass"><span> Banana</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/90cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr data-index="1">
                    <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass"><span> Grapes</span></td>
                      <td>30Nos./70cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text" ng-model="qty"> g </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass"><span> Guava</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/50cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> g </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass"><span> Jackfruit</span></td>
                      <td>4 pieces/90cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Mango</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/180cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Mosambi/orange</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/40cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Papaya</span></td>
                      <td>1 piece/80cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Pineapple</span></td>
                      <td>1 piece/50cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Sapota</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/80cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Watermelon/muskmelon</span></td>
                      <td>1 slice/15cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>
                      <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox"><span> Custard apple</span></td>
                      <td>1 medium/130cal</td>
                      <td><input type="text"> Nos. </td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="uneditable-input" placeholder="aa"> cal.</td>
                    </tr>



                  </tbody>
```

html code for right table:

```
        <table class="table rt-table rt-table-border" id="tbl2">
        <thead style="background-color: #dff0d8">
            <tr>

              <th style="line-height: 11px !important;">Name</th>
              <th style="line-height: 11px !important;">Portion</th>
              <th style="line-height: 11px !important;">Calorie</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="">


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and the script

```
     $(window).load(function(){
  $("#tbl1 input:checkbox.chkclass").click(function(){
//var fs=$(this).parent('div')
//  var span = $('span [for="'+this.id+'"]',fs)

    if ($(this).is(":checked"))

    {
     $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#tbl2");

/*
 $('#tbl2').append('<tr data-for="'
                        +span.text()
                        +'"><td>'
                        +span.text()
                        +'</td><td>'
                        +$(this).attr('value')
                        +'</td></tr>');

*/


    }
    else
    {
      var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
      var findRow = $("#tbl2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
      findRow.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

The commented code gives me undefined and un-commented code give the whole row.

I know the question is long, needed to give a descriptive idea.

Comment: its nothing wrong with your code. Append to `<tbody>` of your table, try this if it helps `$(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#tbl2 tbody");`

Comment: Yes, I can take the row from one table and display in another, I want only three columns from first row to be displayed in the second table. Like take the <span> text and the next two columns.

Comment: I have created an jsfiddle link just check it and let me know if it was your requirement.

Comment: Do not forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied, it might help someone else also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a jsfiddle for you hope it works for you. [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/w3L96qb7/5/)

you can use the following code:

```
$("#tbl1 input:checkbox.chkclass").click(function(){
   var html = '';
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).next().clone().appendTo("#tbl2");
     $(this).parent().next().next().clone().appendTo("#tbl2");
     $(this).parent().next().next().next().clone().appendTo("#tbl2");
   } else {
     var index = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
     var findRow = $("#tbl2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
     findRow.remove();
   }
});
```

Note: There are other alternates too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, this satisfies most of the requirement thanks. though it adds columns after the <tbody> or inside if u edit the code and not a <tr> first and then <td> also i want the text in the second table. not the checkbox. Just "Apple" and no text box in front in the second table.

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/w3L96qb7/5/ could you accept the answer now it will be helpful for someone like you looking for it